# Printing Via Bluetooth on iOS

Tags: ios, printing, bluetooth, airprint

I am new to iOS development. I have a task to develop an iOS app which connects to Bluetooth printer using Bluetooth and complete a printing task.

I have few questions they are as follows

1) Does iOS support Bluetooth printing?

2) If my printer is AirPrint enabled but not connected to the WiFi and If I paired this printer using Bluetooth on my iOS device then will my AirPrint app recognize it and able to print it? I mean if I have an AirPrint enabled printer then wifi is an essential interface for connectivity or we can use Bluetooth as well?

3) Can I develop an app which can connect and print on a printer which is not AirPrint enabled?

I have searched on the Internet, nobody talks about Bluetooth printing. Everybody is saying wifi is essential for AirPrint. Also, i have found that we can not develop apps for that printer which are not AirPrint enabled. Please guide me.

Comment: check this may be it will help i m not sure but may be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102369/ios-swift-3-printer-bluetooth

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about a [thermal printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_printing) and NOT about a [inkjet printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkjet_printing).
AirPrint only works with inkjet printers so if you are using a bluetooth thermal printer AirPrint and Google Cloud Print can't be used.

iOS and macOS SDKs supports Bluetooth 4.0 LE devices with the Core Bluetooth framework and other Bluetooth versions devices with the External Accessory framework. The External Accessory framework requires that the manufacturer of the bluetooth thermal printer is registered in the Mfi Program. Only the major manufacturers like Epson, Star Micronics, Zebra, Bixolon are registered with Mfi Program.

If you buy a cheap bluetooth thermal printer online from a minor manufacturer it will only work with iOS if it uses Bluetooth 4.0 LE since it uses the Core Bluetooth framework which does not require any registration to the Mfi Program.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pod as it helped me to print to a bluetooth printer.

```
pod file
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'Printer', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Check [CocoaPods / Printer](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Printer) for more details.